# Master Detail webform or connecting/linking two webforms

Tags: webforms

I just got a project request that went from simple to complex.

the original project was just to collect basic user info, the complexity comes in, now they want the user to provide detail on his/her car or cars.  So one submission could have 1 2, 5 detail entries.

is it possible to do a master/detail setup using drupal webforms?  i need to create a webform that will have a general info in the top, ex: fname, lastname, age, location, range

there will also be a detail section of their webform that will contain: car type, partID, quantity, type, past requests for example.

Is there away to connect two webforms as there could be several details related to one submission?

**Example**:
Were I doing this in straight php, i would have a master/detail tables
one take holding the fname, lfname, age, location range date
one table holding car type, partID, quantity, type, past requests 
the later table would have a key to connect the items to the first table, easy

How can I accomplish this, or can I accomplish this using webform?

I did a search on connect, link, combine webforms, but not getting anything concrete back, so want to see if i need to rethink the entire process before continuing down the rabbit hole.

Any ideas, advice suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: out of curiosity, why webforms? Drupal 7 allows you to add fields to user profiles and even require the user to complete them on registration, and you could just create a content type to collect the info about the users cars

Comment: Hi trey - i really needed a form like entry point for my users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who come along with a similar issue - my solution here was to use the entityform and fieldcollection modues.  the fieldcollection module allow you to attached a group of sub fields to the entityfield, then you can add more of the subfields as needed.  Querying and views were also fairly easy to set up.